# Git strategy to merge a separated branch with individual commits, into base branch

Tags: git

On my team we have an epic story to be developed in a period of time, and we are many developers doing individual stories (related with this epic story).

Example: let's name this epic as "Update FAQ web page"
Some available stories will be like:

- "Change FAQ page color"
- "Change FAQ font style"
- "Reorder FAQ questions"

etc

To avoid merge isolated stories into `master`, and considering other teams (working on other epics) will be constantly updating our `master` branch, we want to do something like this:

- Start creating a separated branch from `master`, named
  `feature/newFAQPage`
- All developers will merge their stories into `feature/newFAQPage`
- A developer will be updating `feature/newFAQPage` with `master` periodically
- Once all our stories were being completed, we want to merge
  whole `feature/newFAQPage` into `master` (basically, merge all stories together at the same time)

My idea is to achieve this, periodically running `git merge master` into `feature/newFAQPage`, so `feature/newFAQPage` will be a mix of FAQ's team changes and non-FAQ's teams changes.

Is this git strategy feasible? If so, is this the best way or there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this git strategy feasible?

Not just feasible but standard. You know this will be a long lived branch, so it is wise to merge `master` into it periodically, perhaps every few days, to reduce the likelihood of conflict and confusion when the time comes to merge this branch into `master`.